# Can't get DispatchGroup to work properly in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, rest, alamofire

Need to wait for some loop of api calls to be finished before updating the UI, but couldn't yet find out why my DispatchGroup.notify() is getting executed before the http calls:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    if isFirstLoad {

        ProgressIndicator.shared.showProgressView(self.view)

        let serviceUrl = MobnerServices.service_base+"GetTrainersAround?lat=\(self.currLatitude!)&lon=\(self.currLongitude!)&radius=50"

        Alamofire.request(serviceUrl).responseJSON{ response in
            do{
                guard let responseData = response.data else{
                    print("No data received.")
                    ProgressIndicator.shared.hideProgressView()
                    return
                }

                let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()

                let retrievedTrainers = try decoder.decode([STTrainer].self, from: responseData)

                self.trainers = retrievedTrainers
                self.isFirstLoad = false

                for trainer in self.trainers{
                    dispatchGroup.enter()

                    let getUserPictureUrl = MobnerServices.service_base+"GetUserPicture?filename=\(trainer.profilePicturePath)"

                    Alamofire.request(getUserPictureUrl).responseImage { response in
                        guard let image = response.result.value else {
                            print(response.error!.localizedDescription)
                            return
                        }

                        self.trainersPictures.append(STTrainerPicture(userId: trainer.userId, profilePicture: image))
                    }

                    dispatchGroup.leave()
                }

                dispatchGroup.wait()

                ProgressIndicator.shared.hideProgressView()
                self.tableView.reloadData()

            }
            catch{
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Does anyone have some tip here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have no `DispatchGroup.notify` in your code, so what are we even talking about?

Comment: I've read in some blogs we could use .wait() instead of .notify().

Comment: We can certainly use `wait` instead of `notify` but then your question should not ask why `notify` is not called. There is no `notify`.

Comment: Guilherme, those blogs are misleading, because using `wait` is almost always the wrong approach. Newer developers love `wait` because it is simple and intuitive, but it results in horrible UX and can introduce problems. In this example, you’ll be blocking on the main thread at `wait`, so you’ll deadlock because Alamofire won’t be able to run its completion handler on that blocked main queue, and, thus, you’ll never reach that `leave` call, and it won’t ever get past that `wait`. The `notify` pattern avoids blocking the main thread, avoiding this problem.

Comment: @Rob, that's true. I noticed when using .wait() the UI won't even get incorrectly updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is that you are calling `dispatchGroup.leave()` in the wrong place. It needs to be inside the completion handler of the async call.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
let decoder = JSONDecoder()

let retrievedTrainers = try decoder.decode([STTrainer].self, from: responseData)

self.trainers = retrievedTrainers
self.isFirstLoad = false

for trainer in self.trainers{
    dispatchGroup.enter()

    let getUserPictureUrl = MobnerServices.service_base+"GetUserPicture?filename=\(trainer.profilePicturePath)"

    Alamofire.request(getUserPictureUrl).responseImage { response in
        guard let image = response.result.value else {
            print(response.error!.localizedDescription)
            dispatchGroup.leave()
            return
        }

        self.trainersPictures.append(STTrainerPicture(userId: trainer.userId, profilePicture: image))
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    ProgressIndicator.shared.hideProgressView()
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You also need to perform the UI updates on the main queue.

Comment: Worked like a charm!

In regards to updating the UI I replaced .wait() by:

`dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main){
                        ProgressIndicator.shared.hideProgressView()
                        self.tableView.reloadData()
                    }`

And it did the trick.. Thanks a bunch

Comment: Yes, that is a good way to handle the UI updates. Please don't forget to accept answers that solve your issue.

Comment: @Rob The wait is inside the first Alamofire completion block so it shouldn't block anything which is why I left it there. But that context isn't clear in my answer so I'll update it.

Comment: Yeah, `wait` is inside an Alamofire completion block, but those completion blocks run on the main queue by default. Thus, you’ll be waiting on the main thread. Your `notify` solves this problem!

Comment: @Rob I've never used Alamofire so I just assumed the completion handlers ran on a background queue. So it would seem Alamofire automatically calls completion handlers on the main queue. I don't like that design decision.

Comment: Yeah they have an optional `queue` parameter in which you can override which queue the completion handlers will use, but it defaults to the main queue. Given that they give you control over it, I don’t necessarily have a problem with this convention. It’s actually pretty convenient. But one just has to be aware of it. Apple’s own API is inconsistent on this. Regardless, good answer.